# How to exit from loading route in case of error

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Hi I ve a loading template at application level which show a big spinner while models are being loaded. if something goes wrong in model loading it keeps showing even if the transition is aborted. How can I remove it going back the origin route?

Comment: Are you specifically handling the error case for the route?

Comment: Handle [error event](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/routing/loading-and-error-substates/#toc_the-code-error-code-event) as @locks mentioned

Comment: @locks no, it should be for any error

Comment: @ykaragol I would use the error hook but than will I be able to transition to the origin route? does transition param include this piece of information?

Comment: `transition.abort();` should do that.